# XPath preceding axis isn't working as I expect

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm having an issue, it's probably more of an understanding problem than an issue, but I wanted to see if anyone could give me a clue or a hint on what I'm doing wrong.

I have 5 `td` elements.  As below.

```
<td class="someTDClass1">
    <span class="aSPANClass">
        <div class="theDivClass">
        </div>
    </span>
</td>

<td class="someTDClass2">
    <span class="aSPANClass">
        <div class="theDivClass">
        </div>
    </span>
</td>

<td class="someTDClass1">
    <span class="aSPANClass">
        <div class="theDivClass">
        </div>
    </span>
</td>

<td class="someTDClass3">
    <span class="aSPANClass">
        <div class="theDivClass">
        </div>
    </span>
</td>

<td class="someTDClass2">
    <span class="aSPANClass">
        <div class="theDivClass">
        </div>
    </span>
</td>
```

Now what I want to do is grab the class from the first `td` of each element.  The `td` class changes.  But the span and the div doesn't.  So I wrote a preceding xpath and it works for the most part but it doesn't grab the last element.  So I only get 4 `td` elements back.  I know, I know, to get the class name use `GetAttribute()`, I'm just locating right now.  Anyone know why this is?  Why doesn't it find the last element?  It's got all the same elements in it.

```
(//span/div[@class='theDivClass']/preceding::td)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your XPath only selects 4 `td` elements rather than 5 is that the `preceding::` axis includes no ancestors, so your last `td` has no `div` for which it exists as a preceding element.

Change

```
//span/div[@class='theDivClass']/preceding::td
```

to

```
//div[@class='theDivClass']/ancestor::td
```

and you'll select all 5 `td` elements as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I had figured it was something along those lines and hadn't even thought about the ancestor axis.